# Zipping value with corresponging flatMap result

Tags: rxjs

Let's say I have a stream of files `filesStream` and a function `uploadFile` which returns a stream of one value (Rx.Observable.fromPromise(...)). Files on the stream can be uploaded via simple `flatMap`:

```
filesStream.flatMap(uploadFile)
```

What I need is to zip files from `filesStream` with corresponding responses from `uploadFile`:

```
zippedStream.subscribe(
    (file, response) => console.log("File " + file.name + " uploaded: " + response.message)
)
```

I've come up with a quite messy approach which does work

```
var zipppedStream = filesStream.flatMap(
    (file) => uploadFile(file).zip(Rx.Observable.just(file), (r, f) => [r, f])
)
```

But I don't really like it since I need to unpack the two-valued array in `subscribe` and it generally looks heavy.
Is it how you do it or I'm missing something?

Comment: `zippedStream.subscribe(
    (file, response)` <--- you cannot have that, since the signature for the `onNext` handler implies there is only one argument passed. You could destructure it though: `zippedStream.subscribe(
    ([file, response])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bypass using `zip` and use the `flatMap` overload instead to accomplish what you want here

```
let zippedStream = fileStream.flatMap(
 (file) => uploadFile(file),
 (file, uploaded) => [file, uploaded]);

zippedStream.subscribe(
 ([file, response]) => console.log("File " + file.name + " uploaded: " + response.message));
```

Comment: This is just what I needed, thanks! Should read the docs more thoroughly.